# Authentication with pgpass not working

Tags: debian, cron, postgresql

I am trying to set-up automatic backup for postgres db on a local headless server on Debian. I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PGPASSFILE='/home/mtn/.pgpass'
pg_dumpall -U db_user --verbose 2>/var/log/postgresql/pgdump.log | gzip > /mnt/bulk-data/db_backup/db_bak.gz
```

Have a `.pgpass` file:

```
-rw-------  1 mtn  mtn     47 Nov 13 10:14 .pgpass
```

with:

```
*:*:*:postgres:guest
*:*:*:db_user:guest
```

And a `sudo crontab -e` job:

```
20 0 * * * /home/mtn/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

`pg_hba`:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

When i try to run it i get:

```
pg_dumpall: error: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "db_user"
```

Where's the mistake?

PS Everything works if i change the script to run as root `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall`.

**UPDATE**:
What worked for me in the end is adding this line to `pg_ident.conf`:

```
omicron           root                    postgres
```

Then to `pg_hba.conf` before everything else:

```
local   all      all                 ident map=omicron
```

And changing script to run `pg_dumpall` as user `postgres` (only because `db_user` didn't have all necessary privilegies to `dumpall`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peer` authentication means postgresql accepts connections over unix socket from specified unix system user without password as specified database user, so trying to use PGPASS is pointless.
More about `peer` access here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html
In your case, your `pg_hba.conf` allows only system user `postgres` to connect all databases as database user `postgres`. I can't see your `db_user` in your `pg_hba.conf`, so it can't connect. `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall` means you switch to system user `postgres` and run `pg_dumpall` as that user connecting as database user `postgres`. That's why it works.